# How to prevent S7 edge from connecting to open WiFi networks?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge running Android 8.0.

Is there a way to prevent the phone from connecting to open wifi networks? If wifi is on, the phone will always connect to any open network within reach, even new networks I had never connected to (so "forgetting" them does nothing).

It's annoying, not to mention a privacy/security risk, because most of these networks require some kind of login via a browser, so connecting to them effectively means disabling internet access.

E.g. I may be walking down the street or in a bus, the phone picks up the network from a cafe, a hotel, a taxi, and whatever I was doing that required a data connection (eg streaming music) stops.

I seem to remember there used to be an option to prevent connections to open wifi network in earlier Android versions, but I can't find it - don't know if it was removed in Android 8 or by Samsung. All the solutions I have found online refer to older versions of Android.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be you have your device [configured to automatically connect to any open wifi](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6327199?hl=en)? That article is for the Nexus devices, so I'm not sure whether or where Samsung devices might have that setting. But [here's an article](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Smartphones-Tablets-Wearables/Disabling-automatic-connection-to-open-WiFi-networks-on-Galaxy/td-p/141301) on that topic for the S7 specifically which you might wish to check.

Comment: The thing for the Nexus doesn't apply to the S7 (no such option). The suggestions in the other link are a start but not a real solution: you can forget networks you have connected to, but you still get connected to new networks you have not encountered. The same applies to restricting networks. I don't understand who on Earth is the genius who decided to remove this feature. Goes to show that, in IT, new versions can often be worse!

Comment: "New" doesn't necessarily mean "better" – but that's not restricted to IT :) I don't know what Samsung did there. For all my devices, I have to explicitly connect to a network once before they auto-connect to it. But then, I neither have a Samsung device nor Android 8…